# Integration Problems in R

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate in R (I am very new to R) the following function: [image: this function]

```
R <-6
N <- 13
Nb <- 4
S_norm <- 0.3
Ao <- 1/8.02e-5

exact_likelihood <- function(psi){
   exact_likelihood_function <- function(logA){
    sum_p = 0
    for (k in seq(N)){
      r <- (exp(logA)*psi)**k
      sum_p <- r + sum_p
    }
    return(exp(-0.5*(((logA - log(Ao))/S_norm)**2))     * exp(-exp(logA)*psi)  * sum_p) 
  }
  return(integrate(exact_likelihood_function,-Inf,Inf,subdivisions=1000L,abs.tol=1E-300)$value)
}
```

I get the error `Error in integrate(exact_likelihood_function, -Inf, Inf, subdivisions = 1000L, : non-finite function value` , not sure why. The function evaluates perfectly in Python.

Comment: The problem is with `logA`, it's a vector with `logA[2] == 2.330652e+02` and `exp(2.330652e+02) == 1.655504e+101`. Then the values of this multiplied by `psi` raised to increasingly larger powers, `k` gives `Inf`.